# Restrict use of module exports in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have two modules:

InternalDefs.js:

```
const internalLevel = 0;

module.exports = {
  internalLevel 
};
```

ExternalDefs.js:

```
const { internalLevel } = require('./InternalDefs');
const exportedLevel = internalLevel;

module.exports = {
  exportedLevel 
};
```

The InternalDefswill contain definitions that should only be used in ExternalDefs.

The functionality if both files will be exported through ExternalDefs and everyone who wishes to use the functionality should only use the ExternalDefs.

This is an encapsulation of the internal operation. For example a database module.

ExternalDefs will have the functions that will be used.
InternalDefs will serve the external functions only.

**So, is there a way to allow only ExternalDefs to require the exports of InternalDefs in Node.js?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a bad idea to try to restrict it like this. Ideally you should define them in one file and whatever is defined internally without being exported would be your internal data. Once exported, it is available for everyone.

But if you must, you can write this code in internalDefs.js to limit it to being required only by externalDefs.js. Add this early to internalDefs.js

```
if (!(module && module.parent && module.parent.filename && module.parent.filename.endsWith && module.parent.filename.endsWith("/ExternalDefs.js")))
  throw new Error("InternalDefs is only allowed to be required by ExternalDefs");
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're saying is that you want a third class to only have access to `ExternalDefs.js` only, and not `InternalDefs.js` by reference to `internalDefs` defined in `ExternalDefs.js`, then it won't.
Any outside class `require`ing `ExternalDefs.js` will only have access to `internalDefs` defined in `ExternalDefs.js` and will not have access to the properties inside `InternalDefs.js`
If that's not you're question, I suggest you elaborate

Comment: That's not my question :) I would like to enable only ExternalDefs.js to gain access to the module exports of InternalDefs.js.

That is, that if another class, say "bla.js" tries to require the exports of InternalDefs.js, it will not work